# How to gracefully exit double piped continuous command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to exit a continuously running program once it outputs the details I am looking for.
The command below is what I have. I'm expecting the command to finish once I have my value in the output. What happens instead is that the command keeps running indefinitely.

```
wscat -c <web_socket_url> | sed -u -n <my_pattern> | head -n 1
```

For clarification: 'wscat' is my continously running program. I am trying to filter the output so that I only get what I need. I'm trying to exit the command by using 'head' to limit the outputted lines to 1.

Comment: If the `wscat` is never terminating, then either  it is not correctly responding to SIGPIPE or it is not generating enough data to ever get a SIGPIPE.  In either case, the short term fix is to send a TERM.  The long term fix in the former case is to fix wscat so that it responds to SIGPIPE properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common trick to use process substitution to only wait for the last stage in the pipeline:

```
head -n 1 < <(wscat -c <web_socket_url> | sed -u -n <my_pattern>)
```

While the `wscat` and `sed` processes will hang around for a while until they try to output and cause the SIGPIPE to propagate backwards, the script itself will continue immediately once `head` exits.

Answer (score 3):

Have the `sed` exit for itself.

```
wscat -c <web_socket_url> | sed -u -n /my_pattern/{ p; q; }'
```

Assuming you might also want a log of your abbreviated output,

```
wscat -c <web_socket_url> | tee $logname | sed -u -n /my_pattern/{ p; q; }'
```

This will still likely collapse and end the `wscat` when the receiving programs terminate. If you want the rest of the output to finish, don't close the pipe.

```
wscat -c <web_socket_url> | sed -u -n /my_pattern/p'
```

`sed` will still be listening even if it only outputs the thing(s) you want to pass along, so `wscat` will keep talking.

Comment: HI. I'm trying to implement all the suggested solutions. The others don't seem to give the desired result: exit wscat instantly after the first output matched by sed and printed. I tried yours as well, but I can't seem to get the sed command correct: `wscat -c <web_socket_url> | sed -u -n 's/.*Tokencode: \([0-9]\+\)\\.*/\1/p'` Can you please try to adjust your command with this in mind?

Comment: Nevermind my comment above, it is now working with @that other guy's suggestion. Thanks for taking the time.